# In Android xml is wrap content a specific dp value?

Tags: android, xml

I was looking at my layout on different screens of the xml noticed wrap layout looked  the same. So, I wondered if the above was true. Help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Wrap Content attribute adjusts the element depending on its' content.

It adjusts its' size and display style according to different dpi values and screen sizes automatically so that you don't need to manually configure your element.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i have understood your question, but the "wrap_content" is like a div in html/css, so if you dont set a proper padding it just leave 1-2dp around the argument.